# JPA parameter outside a where clause

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I would like to know if the is a way to build a JPA query with parameter outside of the where clause. This query works fine in my database manager.

There is my query :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT q.quote, q.author, q.display_at, count(ql.*) AS like, (SELECT '{:userUUID}'::uuid[] && ARRAY_AGG(ql.user_uuid)::uuid[]) AS liked " +
        "FROM quotes q " +
        "LEFT JOIN quotes_likes ql ON ql.quote_uuid = q.uuid " +
        "WHERE display_at = :date " +
        "GROUP BY q.quote, q.author, q.display_at;", nativeQuery = true)
Optional<QuoteOfTheDay> getQuoteOfTheDay(UUID userUUID, LocalDate date);
```

I have the following error when the query is called : ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"

Comment: have you tried positional parameters? `SELECT '{?1}'::uuid[]` `WHERE display_at =?2` or even `SELECT '{?}'::uuid[]` `WHERE display_at =?`

Comment: Yes but its not working. I've tried the two way.

Answer (score 0):

`ERROR: syntax error at or near` means that you need to escape casting colons.

Every `:` needs to be replaced by `\\:`

```java
(SELECT ARRAY[:userUUID]'\\:\\:uuid[] && ARRAY_AGG(ql.user_uuid)\\:\\:uuid[]) AS liked
```

OR use double colons

```java
(SELECT ARRAY[:userUUID]::::uuid[] && ARRAY_AGG(ql.user_uuid)::::uuid[]) AS liked
```

OR use [Cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createcast.html) instead of colons

```java
(SELECT cast(ARRAY[:userUUID] as uuid[]) && cast(ARRAY_AGG(ql.user_uuid) as uuid[])) AS liked
```

The second problem is that you need to create an array with a query parameter.

Try `ARRAY[:userUUID]` instead of `{:userUUID}`

Full query example:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT q.quote, q.author, q.display_at, count(ql.*) AS like, (SELECT ARRAY[:userUUID]\\:\\:uuid[] && ARRAY_AGG(ql.user_uuid)\\:\\:uuid[]) AS liked " +
        "FROM quotes q " +
        "LEFT JOIN quotes_likes ql ON ql.quote_uuid = q.uuid " +
        "WHERE display_at = :date " +
        "GROUP BY q.quote, q.author, q.display_at;", nativeQuery = true)
Optional<QuoteOfTheDay> getQuoteOfTheDay(UUID userUUID, LocalDate date);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring Data JPA uses position-based parameter binding. We can also use named parameter with @Param annotation to give a method parameter a concrete name and bind the name in the query. As you are trying to use the named parameter try using the below snippet with @Param annotations.

```
Optional<QuoteOfTheDay> getQuoteOfTheDay(@Param("userUUID") UUID userUUID, @Param("date") LocalDate date);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to pass method parameters to the query using named parameters, We define these using the `@Param` annotation inside our repository method declaration.

Each parameter annotated with `@Param` must have a value string matching the corresponding JPQL or SQL query parameter name.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT q.quote, q.author, q.display_at, count(ql.*) AS like, (SELECT '{:userUUID}'::uuid[] && ARRAY_AGG(ql.user_uuid)::uuid[]) AS liked " +
        "FROM quotes q " +
        "LEFT JOIN quotes_likes ql ON ql.quote_uuid = q.uuid " +
        "WHERE display_at = :date " +
        "GROUP BY q.quote, q.author, q.display_at;", nativeQuery = true)
Optional<QuoteOfTheDay> getQuoteOfTheDay(@Param("userUUID") UUID userUUID,@Param("date") LocalDate date);
```

Refer this for more details on [how to use the @Query annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query).